# Change a View's height based on screen resolution in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I want to change my view's height based on the screen size. say for a 3" screen it has to be 60dp and for a 5" screen it has to be 100dp. How can I get this?

Comment: You need to define different size in demen and use it in your view

Comment: As you are asking, try with getting screen height, and divide the height by some value, which possibly set with your output. This is the simplest solution I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Screen dimension(Height and width) of device then you can set Height and width of Element (Button/Edittext/LinearLayout), But remember it require a right calculation for displaying an element in right position.

you could do something like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x; // int screenWidth = display.getWidth(); on API < 13
int screenHeight = size.y; // int screenHeight = display.getHeight(); on API <13

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(something * screenWidth, something * screenHeight); // This should set the witdh and height of the TextView
lp.setMargins( something * screenWidth, something * screenHeight, 0, 0); // This serves as the settings for the left and top position

txtV.setHeight(something * screenHeight);
txtV.setWidths(something * screenWidth);
txtV.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide `diff dimens.xml files` in each `value-sw600dp,value-sw720dp,value-hdpi,value-tvdpi`(`for example`) folder so that your layout will pick values based on screen size.Hope this helps you.